# Restlet routing does not work with Directory in the route?

Tags: java, restlet

I'm having a bit of trouble making these Restlet Server Resources to work:

```
  private static final String ROOT_URI = "/rest/";
  @Override
  public Restlet createInboundRoot() {
    Router router = new Router(getContext());
    Directory directory = new Directory(getContext(), "war:///doc");
    directory.setIndexName("app.html");
    router.attach(ROOT_URI + "files", GaeFilesServerResource.class);
    router.attach(ROOT_URI + "files/{file_id}", GaeFileServerResource.class);
    router.attach("/gwtapp/", directory); // This is the only one that works
    router.attach("/", RootServerResource.class);
    return router;
  }
```

As described in the comment the route /gwtapp/ is the only one that works. Accessing `http://localhost:8080/gwtapp/` forward to `http://localhost:8080/gwtapp/app.html` which is correct.

**The question is:**

I wonder why those under `/` and `/rest/` would not work in this case?

Comment: Would it be possible to enable traces in your application and provide the traces regarding route matching? Thanks!

Comment: @thierrytemplier can you check my answer below

Comment: @thierrytemplier BTW do you think you can help us setup a Restlet gitter chat room?

Comment: It seems to be a strange behavior. I made a test with the version 2.3.4 on the `jse` edition and your code works. Which version of Restlet do you use?

Comment: @thierrytemplier I'm using 2.3.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution was to attach:

```
router.attachDefault(RootServerResource.class);
```

instead.